# Use sensitive information rather than hard-coding react native

Tags: security, react-native, amazon-s3, credentials

I have some information in my react native app which is considered sensitive. It is the accessKey and secretKey for my S3 instance.

Is there a command line tool to add these variables to the keychain, rather than having to hard code them into the code.

It is currently working with credentials in the code, but if it's possible I'd like to take them out.

Ideally, what I'm looking for are some global variables that I can set from the command line and then use in my application code. For instance run: `$ ACCESS_KEY = 1234567890` from the command line, and then in my code I can just get the `ACCESS_KEY` variable.

Thanks,